# What is meaning of this question and how to solve it?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, functional-equations

I am stuck with understanding the meaning of the question, which states:

> Show that $\cos(n\theta)=f_n(\cos\theta)$ for polynomials $f_n(x)$ satisfying $$f_{n+1}(x)=2xf_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x) \tag{1}$$ Find all roots of $f_2(x)+f_3(x)=0$, and write them in the form $\cos(\phi)$ for suitable $\phi$

How should I solve this question?
Does the first part mean 'given the relation $(1)$, deduce $\cos(n\theta)=f_n(\cos\theta)$'? Or does it mean to show $\cos(n\theta)=f_n(\cos\theta)$ satisfy $(1)$?

Comment: It means your first thought: Given a sequence of polynomials satisfying (1), show that evaluating $f_n$ at $x = \cos\theta$ yields $\cos(n\theta)$.

Comment: I think it is to show that the relation satisfies the equation. You cannot deduce it without initial condition. There may be different polynomial solution aka [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One has
$$\cos(0x)=1,\quad \cos(1x)=\cos x,\qquad\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x-1\ .$$
This shows that for $0\leq n\leq 2$ the functions $x\mapsto \cos(nx)$ can be written "as  polynomials in $\cos x\>$". Furthermore, it follows from the addition theorem for $\cos$ that
$$\cos\bigl((n+1)x\bigr)+\cos\bigl((n-1)x\bigr)=2\cos(nx)\cos x\ ,$$
since the $\sin$ terms cancel. The last formula can be written as
$$\cos\bigl((n+1)x\bigr)=2\cos x\cos(nx)-\cos\bigl((n-1)x\bigr)\qquad(n\geq1),\tag{1}$$
and serves now as a recursion formula for the successive $\cos(n\cdot)$. In particular it provides an induction proof that all functions $x\mapsto \cos(nx)$, $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$,  can be written "as  polynomials in $\cos x\>$".

In order to describe this in a more abstract way one introduces an "indeterminate" $X$ (this is just a letter, and is not to be interpreted a priori as a real variable), and defines a sequence of polynomials $(f_n)_{n\geq0}$ in this indeterminate recursively as follows:
$$f_0(X)=1, \quad f_1(X)=X,\qquad f_{n+1}(X):=2X f_n(X)-f_{n-1}(X)\ .\tag{2}$$
The polynomials $f_n$ produced in this way are called *Chebyshev polynomials*. It is easy to see that ${\rm deg}\,(f_n)=n$ for all $n$. Above all, a comparison of $(1)$ and $(2)$ immediately shows that
$$\cos(nx)=f_n(\cos x)\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R})$$
for all $n\geq0$.

One obtains $f_2(X)=2X^2-1$ and $f_3(X)=2Xf_2(X)-f_1(X)=4X^3-3X$. We now are told to solve
$$4X^3+2X^2-3X-1=0\tag{3}$$
for (complex) $X$. One immediately checks that $X=-1$ is a solution, so that one could deflate $(3)$ to a quadratic equation – I leave that to you. But we are given a hint: Our equation is "special". The substitution $$X:=\cos x\qquad (0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ transforms it into 
$$0=\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)=2\cos{5x\over2}\cos{x\over2}\ .$$
This is fulfilled if one of the following is true:
$${5x\over2}={\pi\over2},\quad{5x\over2}={3\pi\over2},\quad{x\over2}={\pi\over2}\ ,$$
or
$$x\in\left\{{\pi\over5}, {3\pi\over5}, \pi\right\}\ .$$
It follows that
$$X=\cos x\in\left\{\cos{\pi\over5}, -\cos{2\pi\over5}, -1\right\}\ .$$
Since we have found three different values for $X$ we don't need to look further. (This "geometric" approach only brings solutions $X\in[{-1},1]$ to the fore.)

Answer (score 1):

The question is:

Given the relationship

$$f_{n+1}(x)=2xf_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)$$

demonstrate that $\cos(n\theta)=f_n(\cos\theta)$. To show this, induction may be useful.

The second part can probably be done through the substitution $x = \cos \theta$ and the relationship from above.

Comment: Is it okay to assume $x$ is always in the range of $\cos \theta$?

Comment: @Rescy_ The question explicitly states the solutions can be written as $\cos \phi$, so I'd assume so. I imagine you could probably find solutions outside the range as well if you considered $\cos$ for imaginary values too.

Answer (score 1):

Christian's answer nicely addresses how to solve the second part, but let me see if I can give some additional insight on *why* we should interpret the first part as he did. (A.G.'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376203/what-is-meaning-of-this-question-and-how-to-solve-it/1377138#comment2801939_1376203) alludes to the problem, too.)

If we are supposed to assume only that $(1)$ holds for all (appropriate) $n$, then it is *not possible* to verify that $\cos(n\theta)=f_n(\cos\theta)$ hold in general. In fact, given any sequence of functions $f_n$ satisfying $(1)$ for all (appropriate) $n$, we have for *any* function $g(x)$ that the sequence of functions $g(x)f_n(x)$ also satisfies $(1),$ but on the other hand, $\cos(n\theta)=g(\cos\theta)f_n(\cos\theta)$ need not hold in general for all such $g$, even if $\cos(n\theta)=f_n(\cos\theta)$ holds in general. Thus, we must conclude that the question is poorly written, that and we are instead supposed to assume (or demonstrate) the existence of a sequence of polynomials satisfying $\cos(n\theta)=f_n(\cos\theta)$ in general, then prove that such a sequence satisfies $(1).$